# Mounting new HDD

Tags: 18.04, permissions, mount

I have searched and found a lot of things so I may have screwed up trying it all.

What I want to do should be easy, but I am new to Ubuntu and how it works.

I installed a 14tb drive in my machine.  I went through and thought I had partitioned it and mounted the drive with /media/music as the mount point.

In /etc/fstab, I added the line as below:  [fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R439z.png)

when I reboot, the initial screen says local is only 1TB, so it is only finding the SSD that I have had before.

I have changed the permissions through chmod to 777 for /media/music

But when I open in plex to add that as the location of the music library, I click on /media, but music is not available.

I have a large library of other media that is on gsuite and I would like to add all of my music to this hard drive, but I can not find a way to get it mounted and usable.

TIA for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your mount point exists and try mounting again:

```
mkdir -p /media/music && mount -a
```

Also, make sure the uuid in fstab is correct for the drive on sdb. Try running blkid to confirm

Comment: I tried this, and used sudo before it, but I get:    mount: only root can use "--all" option.  I thought that sudo made me root?

Comment: sudo runs a single command as the root user. I should have been clearer above. Either become root by running "sudo -i" (without quotes) and run the command exactly as it looks above. Or run "sudo mkdir -p /media/music && sudo mount -a"

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting the hang of this stuff.  I did what you said, and still having issues.  I'll have to keep playing with it, I'm sure it's a simple fix and I have something that I'm overlooking.